# Multiple usage of a parameter in a SQLCommand C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-4.0

I need to ask something again. I'm a PHP developer for two years. Previously, I got my hands with Java for a year and C# for at least some couple of months before Java. I'm in the process of relearning C#. The following C# `string` declaration is from a tested `SQL` script that determines if a reservation entry (from the `[RESERVATION]` table) overlaps with an existing `Pending` reservation (filtered by the `[status] as [r]` where clause)

```
string query = "select [r].[id], [first_name], [middle_name], [surname], [extension], [reservation_time_from], [reservation_time_to] " +
    "from [RESERVATION] as [r] " +
        "join [CUSTOMER] as [c] on [r].[customer_id] = [c].[id] " +
    "where [reservation_date] = @reservation_date and " +
        "( @reservation_time_from between [reservation_time_from] and [reservation_time_to] or " +
            "@reservation_time_to between [reservation_time_from] and [reservation_time_to] " +
        ") or " +
        "( [reservation_time_from] between @reservation_time_from and @reservation_time_to " +
            "or [reservation_time_to] between @reservation_time_from and @reservation_time_to " +
        ") and " +
        "[status] = 'Pending' " +
    "order by [transaction_date] asc";
```

I attached the parameters using this method:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue();
```

Now when I perform the query using the `command.ExecuteReader()`, it seems that the query does not fetch overlap schedules of `[RESERVATION]`. I got a hunch that it has something to do with the source of the data: that is a `DateTimePicker` object; since the column type of the columns are `date` only, but I'm not quite sure. I attached the values of those time picker using this code (that is a parameter for a `time` column):

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reservation_time_from", SqlDbType.Date).Value = ((DateTime)param[value]).TimeOfDay;
```

Can someone assist me? Note though that some parameters (such as `@reservation_time_from`) occurred **at least twice** on the query `string`. Thanks for the support.

## EDIT:

These is how I attached parameters (sorry the previous example is wrongly pasted, Tee hee):

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reservation_time_from", SqlDbType.Time).Value = ((DateTime)param['reservation_time_from']).TimeOfDay;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reservation_time_to", SqlDbType.Time).Value = ((DateTime)param['reservation_time_to']).TimeOfDay;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reservation_date_from", SqlDbType.Date).Value = ((DateTime)param['reservation_date_from']).Date;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reservation_date_to", SqlDbType.Date).Value = ((DateTime)param['reservation_date_to']).Date;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my bad, it seems that **I've slightly overlooked the mapping of sql type**  on some of the `parameters`:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reservation_date_from", SqlDbType.Date).Value = ((DateTime)param['reservation_date_from']).Date;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reservation_date_to", SqlDbType.Date).Value = ((DateTime)param['reservation_date_to']).Date;
```

Instead of using `SqlDbType.Date`, I must use `SqlDbType.DateTime`. I overlooked that the `sql type` of the columns `[reservation_date_from]` and `[reservation_date_to]` are both `DateTime`. Now the overlap trap works like a charm. Sorry for the silly mistake...

Answer (score 1):

[`AddWithValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) takes the *value* as the second parameter, and so is interpreting the SqlDbType as the parameter value. You will need to use `Add` instead of `AddWithValue`:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@reservation_time_from", SqlDbType.Time)
                  .Value = ((DateTime)param[value]).TimeOfDay;
```

From the documentation:

> AddWithValue replaces the SqlParameterCollection.Add method that takes
>   a String and an Object. The overload of Add that takes a string and an
>   object was deprecated because of possible ambiguity with the
>   SqlParameterCollection.Add overload that takes a String and a
>   SqlDbType enumeration value **where passing an integer with the string
>   could be interpreted as being either the parameter value or the
>   corresponding SqlDbType value.**

Edit: what you're doing only works because the SqlCommand is correctly assigning the SqlDbType based on the value provided in the `Value` set and the SqlDbType is irrelevant: run this code to see:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand();
var param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_from", SqlDbType.Date);
Console.WriteLine(param.ParameterName);
Console.WriteLine(param.SqlDbType);
Console.WriteLine(param.Value.GetType());

Console.WriteLine();

param.Value = DateTime.Today;
Console.WriteLine(param.ParameterName);
Console.WriteLine(param.SqlDbType);
Console.WriteLine(param.Value.GetType());
```

This outputs:

```
@date_from
Int
System.Data.SqlDbType

@date_from
DateTime
System.DateTime
```